# How to use external libraries managed by Maven in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

While importing org.apache.commons.math3 library with Maven (editing the pom.xml file), IntelliJ 2019 seems to update correctely the "External Libraries" and "Dependencies" nodes but later, when trying to use the library happens that symbols are not resolved and looks like the program is not able to reference that library even if Maven imported them correctely. Using the "import" keyword, IntelliJ seems to be unable to reference the library.

Answer (score 0):

I sort out that declaring the full path of the class declared inside the external library (see example below), IntelliJ proposes to the library reference to module-info.java, contained inside the browser tree of the IntelliJ project. If the full path is not declared, IntelliJ does not ask to modify the module-info.java file. After the reference is added to module-info.java, than the IntelliJ "intellisense" is able to resolve the symbols.

```
public class GastTank implements org.apache.commons.math3.ode.FirstOrderDifferentialEquations{
    @Override
    public int getDimension() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void computeDerivatives(double v, double[] doubles, double[] doubles1) {

    }
}
```